# Viewport / Rendered Cycles problem Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I have a strange problem with cycles 
in the rendered viewport everything looks fine but when i render the scene
suddenly it doesn't look good specially on the walls

anyone has any idea why is it that happening?
[image: Viewprot]

[image: Rendered Scene]

Comment: I guess either modifiers are disabled for rendering (screen icon) or there is any additional object probably hidden for viewport rendering (overlapping geometry). It would help to solve your issue, if you would add a screenshot providing information about your scene settings or upload the file preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for the respond... the geometry is ok and there are no overlapping faces and the normals are ok and facing the camera ..... and there are no modifiers ...that's why i find this strange

Comment: and with eevee everything is allright ....I'm trying it again using the Luxcore renderer to see if the problem is only with cycles